# Searching in json-server

Tags: javascript, json-server

I am trying to use json-server using npm

```
  {  
   "refunded":{  
      "data":[  
         {  
            "order_id":"8",
            "order_no":"o000000008",
            "orderdate":"2018-01-23 23:20:00",
            "ordertype":"TakeAway",
            "invoice_Id":"10"
         },
         {  
            "order_id":"9",
            "order_no":"o000000009",
            "orderdate":"2018-01-23 23:20:00",
            "ordertype":"TakeAway",
            "invoice_Id":"11"
         },
         {  
            "order_id":"12",
            "order_no":"o000000012",
            "orderdate":"2018-01-24 00:05:00",
            "ordertype":"TakeAway",
            "invoice_Id":"12"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I am able to access `http://localhost:3000/refunded` without any problem. Now I want to records inside **data** array. e.g. `http://localhost:3000/refunded?order_no=8`.

How can I achieve it. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: "How can I achieve it." - by attempting to program :)

Comment: I assume that json-server gives some sql server like facilities (for faking data only I know), so i tried to use its inbuilt function..

Answer (score 0):

Json-server only accept one level object so try this.

```
{  
   "refunded":[  
         {  
            "order_id":"8",
            "order_no":"o000000008",
            "orderdate":"2018-01-23 23:20:00",
            "ordertype":"TakeAway",
            "invoice_Id":"10"
         },
         {  
            "order_id":"9",
            "order_no":"o000000009",
            "orderdate":"2018-01-23 23:20:00",
            "ordertype":"TakeAway",
            "invoice_Id":"11"
         },
         {  
            "order_id":"12",
            "order_no":"o000000012",
            "orderdate":"2018-01-24 00:05:00",
            "ordertype":"TakeAway",
            "invoice_Id":"12"
         }
      ]
}
```